# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't seem to execute my .profile file

Tags: gnome, scripts, .profile

(I'm kinna n00bish)

1: I had ubuntu 11.10 installed, then upgraded to 12.04.

2: I had a script in my .profile file to turn off my laptop's touchpad (it worked, and was executed on login)

3: Now it doesn't get executed on login.

4: if I 'source .profile' the script still works.

5: Still using gnome (if that matters)

I need that script to be run on login, so what should I do?

Should i put my personal scripts in another file, or is there a way to get ubuntu to execute my file again?

Thx, you guys rule!

Comment: It should still be sourced by lightdm when you log in. Make sure it can be sourced by sh, and from any directory. E.g. this test should work: `sh -c 'cd / && . ~/.profile'`

Comment: the command executes the file correctly.

Comment: Then perhaps running the script from `.profile` is too soon in the login process. Try running the script via Startup Applications instead.

Comment: thx. I did that. It seems like it should work the old way too, so i'll keep investigating, but in the mean time your solution keeps my boat from sinking, so thx.

Comment: I have this problem also. I have a .profile that simply sources another .profile_ex, but beginning with 12.04, the .profile appears not to be run, despite the indication that it should be in its header.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a .bash_profile or .bash_login in your home directory.  There are these comments in the .profile file:

```
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

Comment: i don't have any of those 2 files. the comments inside .profile, the examples indicated will help me figure this out eventually, so thx.